# getting String types not allowed (at 'paintStroke' with value '4f') error for float type value attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-custom-attributes

Im using custom attributes for my custom view in my android application. I want to give a float value for my custom attribute.

**res/values/attrs.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <resources>
      <declare-styleable name="CanvasView">
        <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="paintColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="paintStroke" format="float"/>
      </declare-styleable>
     </resources>
```

**res/layout/view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.example.canvaspoc.CanvasView
        xmlns:customAttrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.canvaspoc"
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        customAttrs:backgroundColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        customAttrs:paintColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        customAttrs:paintStroke="4f"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I try to run the application it is giving me the following error

> Error:(15, 34) String types not allowed (at 'paintStroke' with value
>   '4f').

**Working snippet** :

We just have to give "4" or "4.0" for custom float attribute values. No need of adding 'f' at the ending.

Comment: why do you need the `f` at the end ?

Comment: Any issues with just 4 or 4.0?

Comment: I need a float value for that attribute , i didnt try 4 . I thought we need to give 'f' at the end for the float value

Comment: Use 4.0 instead !

Comment: Just giving 4 or 4.0 works . Thanks guys